# Incorrect syntax near '('.

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I tried to run the program I got the error:

> Incorrect syntax near '('.

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
com.Connection = con;
SqlDataReader dr;

string query = "Update Emp SET(id,dt,Nam,Desig,Address,Phone,UserId) Values(@id,@dt,@Nam,@Desig,@Address,@Phone,@UserId)";
com.CommandText = query;

com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id",(int)nid));
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dt",(object)txtDOJ.Value.ToString()));
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Nam",(object)txtName.Text));
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Desig",(object)txtDesig.Text));
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Address",(object)txtAddress.Text));
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Phone",(object)txtPhone.Text));
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userId",(object)txtUserId.Text));

com.ExecuteNonQuery();   //I am getting incorrect syntax near '(' error here;

MessageBox.Show("Save!");
getlist();
```

Comment: you need an extra space in the command, `UPDATE Emp SET (` instead of  `UPDATE Emp SET(`. Same applies to `Values`

Comment: Update and Insert do not have same format : string query = "Update Emp SET id=@id,dt=@dt,Nam=@Nam,Desig=@Desig,Address=@Address,Phone=@Phone,UserId=@UserId";

Comment: Be careful, you don't have a where clause, this sentence will update all the rows.

Comment: You should find a good SQL book or online tutorial to learn basic syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Your query should look like:

```
string query = "Update Emp SET id=@id,
                               dt=@dt,
                               Nam=@Nam,
                               Desig=@Desig,
                               Address=@Address,
                               Phone=@Phone,
                               UserId=@UserId" ;
```

Look hier about Update Statement:  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Mention comment from @Jose Luis : This  statement will update **ALL** rows. If you don't want it you should add `Where` clause to it.

Comment: incase of a student database how can I update the selected row details only

Comment: @Aspiring_mind I don't know what a student database is and what is your selected row, if you do know the id of the row,  just add "where id =@selectedId" and don't forget to set parameters selectedId Value.

Comment: can you make me understand with the help of an example